# printing a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I am a relative newcomer to R. I have searched for the last two workdays trying to figure this out and failed. I have a list of factors generated by a function. I have 9 items in the list of different lengths.

```
>summary(list_dataframes)
      Length Class  Mode   
 [1,] 1757   factor numeric
 [2,] 1776   factor numeric
 [3,] 1737   factor numeric
 [4,] 1766   factor numeric
 [5,] 1783   factor numeric
 [6,] 1751   factor numeric
 [7,] 1744   factor numeric
 [8,] 1749   factor numeric
 [9,] 1757   factor numeric
```

Part of a sample of the data as it comes out:

> list_dataframes

```
[[1]]

[1] 1776234_at   1779003_at   1776344_at   1777664_at   1772541_at   1774525_at  

 [[2]]

 [1] 1771703_at   1776299_at   1772744_at   1780116_at   1775451_at   1778821_at  

[7] 1774342_at 

 [[3]]

[1] 1780116_at   1776262_at   1775451_at   1780200_at   1775704_at
```

I am not sure why it says the Mode is "numeric". The individual entries are a mix of numbers and letter like "S35_at".

I would like to make this into a table of nine columns and 1783 rows without making duplicate values. (Hence I tried using do.call and it didn't work. I ended up with a mess full of duplicates.) The shorter ones can have NAs in the empty spaces or be blank.

I need to be able to eventually end up with something I can put into a spread sheet.

There has to be a way to do this. Thank you!

I guess I should add it initially was coming out as data frames when I had four columns of data but I only need one column of the data and when I subsetted the function that creates this list to create only the one column I actually needed it seems to no longer be a dataframe.

```
dput(head(list_dataframes))
list(structure(c(3605L, 5065L, 3663L, 4349L, 1655L, 2700L, 5692L, plus many more
.Label = c("1769308_at", 
"1769311_at", "1769312_at", "1769313_at", "1769314_at", "1769317_at", plus many more
this pattern is repeated nine more times
```

What I am trying to do is produce a table that would look like this:

```
a= xyz,tuv,efg,hij,def
b= xyz,tuv,efg
c= tuv,efg,hij,def
```

What I want to make is a table that is

```
a    b    c
xyz  xyz  tuv
tuv  tuv  efg
efg  efg  hij
hij  NA   NA
NA   NA   NA

NA could be blank as well.
```

After much reading the manual section on lists I determined that I had generated a buried list of lists. It had nine items with the data I wanted buried two layers down i.e to see it I had to use [[1]]. Also because of something in R that results in a single column data frame becoming a factor instead of staying a data frame it was further complicated. To fix it (sort of) I added one step in my equation so that I changed that factor into a data frame.

After that, when I used lapply to generate my result, at least the factor issue was resolved. I could then use the following steps to pull the data frames out.

```
first <- list_dataframes[[1]]
second <- list_dataframes[[2]]
third <- list_dataframes[[3]]
fourth <- list_dataframes[[4]]
fifth <- list_dataframes[[5]]
sixth <- list_dataframes[[6]]
seventh <- list_dataframes[[7]]
eighth <- list_dataframes[[8]]
nineth <- list_dataframes[[9]]

all_results <- cbindX(first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh, eighth,nineth)
```

I could then write the csv file using write.csv and get the correct result I was after. SO I guess I have my answer. I mean it does work now.

However I still think I am missing something in making this work optimally even though it is now giving me the correct result I was after.

Comment: Perhaps post a reproducible example showing a subset of the data set, perhaps with 10-20 rows.

Comment: There is a very limited degree of overlap in that data. Your initial description suggested a high degree of overlap. Care to clarify?

Comment: It's lists of things I am working on that have a certain value that makes them significant. The subsets are all taken from the same larger set of 4500 and there is some overlap between them but not a lot. The issue with duplicates in do.call is that I would have 50 or 60 duplicates in the final column sets. I could manually remove them from the spreadsheet but that would defeat the point in learning to program things.

Comment: I do not yet understand what you want. You say you want "a table of nine columns and 1783 rows without making duplicate values", but your description of the data situation appears to make that impossible. Try illustrating what you want with with a smaller list of factors, say lengths 8, 9, and 10 that only have a few values in common. I do not see how this could get organized as you request, but sometimes a concrete example would get me over the conceptual barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor class variables are vectors of integer mode with an attached attribute that is a character vector specifying the labels to be used in displaying the integer values.  I would think the safest way to bind these together would be to convert the factor columns to character class and then to `merge` with `all=TRUE`. Why not post a simple example with three dataframes or factors... I cannot actually discern the structure for sure from summary-output ... of length 10, 9  and 8 that has whatever level of complexity is in your data?

If you want to make them all factors with a common set of levels, then use this:

```
 shared_levels <- unique( c( unlist( lapply(list_dataframes) ) ) )
 length(shared_levels)
 new_list <- lapply(list_dataframes, factor, levels=shared_levels)
```

As stated in the comment, I still do not understand what sort of table you imagine being produced. Need a concrete example.

Comment: I have tried to change the convert the factor columns to character class but I was only able to change the mode. How should I do that?

Comment: You should post `dput(head(object))` so there is a reproducible example. The printed output does not suggest these are factors since no levels are printed. The function that converts factors to character is `as.character`.

Comment: That generates a very very large file I could even begin to post here. I added a short subset. I am also rereading the manual about lists because I think the solution is in there.

Comment: I tried your solution and got "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default" I am sorry if that is because I am messing it up somehow. But your other comment got me thinking and it did lead me to a solution that worked even if I don;t think it is the best way.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. i really do appreciate it.